# Why can't I download certain tracks I purchased in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad, music, mp3

Some months ago, I purchased a couple of tracks from iTunes. I purchased them on my iPad. Now I would like to transfer them to my desktop computer so I can then transfer them to an mp3 player. I signed in to iTunes on my desktop and went to all my Purchased music. Most of the tracks have the Cloud icon to download them. However those other two tracks don't have it, ie the Cloud icon is just not there. I'm assuming they won't be downloaded even if I click "Download All."

What can I do? I just want to transfer these two tracks to an mp3 player and I'm not sure how to do that from my iPad where the two tracks were originally downloaded. I was able to do so with most of the other tracks, but these two won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the iCloud symbol in your library means the file has yet to be downloaded, therefore it's absence also generally means that the file has been downloaded and is locally present. Try downloading the ones with iCloud symbols then doing your transfer.

If I am misinterpreting this and you can't transfer the files at all, whilst your iPad is connected there is a "Transfer Purchases" button under File > Devices in iTunes's menu bar to transfer files directly.